# How to set working directoy when you ssh into a server?

Tags: ssh, openssh

The OpenSSH [config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) file has many great options to easily log in to a host by typing `ssh foo`. How can I specify the default working directory for each host? e.g. `/srv` so I don't need to run `cd /srv` each time?

Comment: Add a conditionalized (e.g. `[ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]`) `cd` in the shell profile file (or rc file, depending on your need) of the remote user?

Comment: @TomYan thanks, I did not get your solution.